# Why aren't these TypeScript type assertions being flagged?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm reviewing type assertions and noticed that the last three variable assignments don't generate errors. Can anyone explain why? I *think* I'm trying to coerce 'helo' into 'hello' and am expecting errors.

The compiler is working in my text editor, as shown at the bottom. So it's caught when I try to do something with the variables, but I'm still surprised it's not detected earlier.

Sometimes rules or validations need to be more flexible to handle different scenarios and that may be why this works, but in this case I'm creating an incompatibility directly at assignment time AFAIK.

(Results are the same with `type Helo = 'helo'`.)

```
  type Helo = string
  type Hello = 'hello'

  let helo: Helo = 'helo'

  // These 3 lines don't generate any errors
  let hello = helo as Hello
  let h = <Hello>'helo'
  let hl = <'hello'>'helo'

  const greet = (msg: Hello) => console.log(msg)
>>greet(helo) // tsserver: 2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"hello"'
```

Comment: type casting (your 3 lines are doing that), checks less strictly if at all. It kinda is an advanced feature that you need to know what you are doing / check yourself. Casting is not really checked in general, like in other languages it is checked even less.

Comment: I don't really like the term `cast` with TypeScript since we're not dealing with actual data types that can be checked/changed at runtime. All you do is *assert* something about a variable.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question. If you have a legitimate reason to delete it, flagging your question is your only option.

Answer (score 2):

You experimented with [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). The reason you don't get any errors is because you bascially tell the compiler *"Hey, I know better than you"* and override any inference done by the compiler. The types of the three variables (`hello`, `h` and `h1`) simply is what you tell them to be.

Also note, there is no difference between the `as` keyword and the angle-bracket syntax.